# How to manage multiple email addresses in squirrelmail without having to create new user accounts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot

I set up squirrelmail on my dovecot/postfix Ubuntu 16.04 mail server. When creating new user accounts I can fetch their emails by just logging into squirrelmail. I now would like to add more addresses to a single account. My first idea was to just add an alias (/etc/aliases), but that only works for receiving mail. How can I send email or reply to an email with such an alias, without having to create a new user account? Is there a way to change the sender address in squirrelmail?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a "Reply To" address in SquirrelMail: look in Options --> Personal Information.

That doesn't set up an actual email address, however: to do that, you need to set up aliases in postfix.